# Getting a direct reference to a private member name instead of using string

Tags: c#, reference, private, member

I'm using a library that requires I pass names of my private members, presumably so it can do some reflection internally:

```
m_MaterialsProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_Materials");
```

As I refactor and move things around it becomes a nightmare to ensure these strings remain correct.

Is it possible for me to get a safe reference to the private member, and pass the member name to the function instead?

Comment: Meaning - you want static (compile time) verification if this property really exists? I believe it is not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
    {
        MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
        return expressionBody.Member.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate usage?

Comment: Will not work, you cannot use private fields access as a expression.

Comment: I've ended up using this:

    public string materialsMemberName {get {return GetMemberName(() => m_Materials);}}

    public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
    {
        return (memberExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }

Answer (score 0):

An approach you could take here (without showing any code, you'll have to look it up for yourself) is to use a custom `Annotation` for `Fields` which are to be used with this library.

Then you could use `Reflection` to find all `Fields` for your class which have your `Annotation`. That way, if you change the name of the actual Field, the Annotation stays intact and you can still find your Fields.

A utility method which takes a class as an argument could give you all of the required Fields for that class.